# How to identify the serial port of a specific Raspberry Pi Pico by changing ProductID

Tags: micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

I am writing drivers to communicate with a raspberry Pi Pico through serial communication. The Raspberry Pi Pico software is written in MicroPython ([rp2 port](https://github.com/micropython/micropython/blob/a00c9d56db775ee5fc14c2db60eb07bab8e872dd/ports/rp2/README.md)) . I need to identify when a specific Raspberry Pi Pico device is connected to the computer, I thought to do this by modifying The Vendor ID or/and the Product ID of the device, how can I do this?  I have already looked inside the Micropython source but couldn't find which constants to modify. Does anyone know a solution?

EDIT

As @David Grayson pointed out I cannot change DEVICE ID and VENDOR ID.  What if I want to change the device description instead? So that doing `lsusb' result in a more informative description.
I currently get the following for my board.

```bash
...
Bus 005 Device 004: ID 2e8a:0005 MicroPython Board in FS mode
...
```

Can I change the description (MicroPython Board in FS mode) in some way?

Comment: You're not supposed to be assigning USB product IDs unless you have paid the USB implementer's forum for your own vendor ID.  If you do it anyway, it can lead to compatibility problems when people are using your device/drivers along with legitimate ones with the same IDs.  (Of course this could have been avoided if the USB specification were designed better in the first place.)

Comment: Ok, get it! What if I want to change the device description?

Comment: I have added an edit to the post.

Comment: What's wrong with using the board's serial number?  I suppose you could add your own USB string descriptor to the device, but then when you try to read it from your program it will probably take extra I/O (which means it is slower and requires permission to access the device), whereas the OS automatically reads the serial number during enumeration.

Answer (score 1):

The latest versions of the MicroPython RP2 port expose the unique ID of the flash chip as a USB serial number, so you should be able to just use the serial number to find your specific device.  Linux makes it really easy by providing symbolic links in `/dev/serial/by-id`, but it is also possible in macOS and Windows.

Comment: This solution is interesting. But what if I don't want to be dependent on the board serial?